# Is there a way to use PHP in your chat box system to produce smiley?

Tags: php

I am trying to analyse the text then when I saw ":)" I will replace it with the path of the image is there a way to make that happened?

Thanks in advance..

```
$text = "This would be fun :)"
```

wanted result = "This would be fun  image *path here*"

so instead of ":)" I will see the path of the image to appear smiley

Comment: I see but can I replace multiple words ?

Comment: yes you can replace multiple.

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano `str_replace()` will work on any occurrence of ":)" in the string you pass.

Comment: nada jud mong brandon

Comment: Thanks guys now I can show smily in my php chat box system :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$text = "This would be fun :)"
$newtext = str_replace(":)", "<img src='images/smiley.png'>", $text);
```

for multiple replace find example below from [php.net](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
// Provides Result: Hll Wrld f PHP
```

Comment: what if there is more than one ":)" ? how to manage changing multiple string ?

Comment: It will replace all occurrences of the ":)" in the string.. ie:  :) :) :) :) :)  <-- it would replace all of them

Comment: yes As @WadeShuler has said it will replace multiple occurrence of :)  from $text string

Answer (score 2):

Thanks kamlesh

as I read about str_replace I derived to this solution

```
  $str = "It would be fun :)";
     $image_path_smile = "<img class='emoticons' src='images/smile.png'/>";

    $pattern=array();
    $pattern[0]=":)";

    $replacement=array();
    $replacement[0]=$image_path_smile;

     str_replace($pattern,$replacement,$str);
```

Thanks for the quick response :)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the following to replace all the textual smiles you may have in a single string with the corresponding `<img>` tags:

```
<?php
class SmileyReplacer {
    private static $smilies = [':)'=>'happy.png', ';)'=>'blink.png', ':('=>'sad.png'];
    private static $address = 'path/to/file/';

    public static function replace($str) {
        foreach(self::$smilies as $smileyTxt => $smileyFile) {
            $str = str_replace($smileyTxt, "<img src=\"".self::$address.$smileyFile."\"/>", $str);
        }
        return $str;
    }
}

echo SmileyReplacer::replace('Hi :), this would be fun ;) but it\'s already over :(');
?>
```